# Ruby on Rails - Access Field Object's Relational Database Item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database, rails-activerecord

I have a many to one relationship between registries...

```
class Registry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_registries
  attr_accessible :logo, :name
  has_attached_file :logo
end
```

and user_registries...

```
class UserRegistry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :page
    has_one :registry
  attr_accessible :page_id, :registry_id, :url
end
```

I'm trying to show the name or logo inside of the form like so:

```
.registry
  = debug f.object.registry.name
  .field
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title
  .field
    = f.label :url
    = f.text_field :url
  .field
    = f.hidden_field :_destroy
    = link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)"
```

But I'm getting an SQL Error, as follows:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'registries.user_registry_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `registries`.* FROM `registries`  WHERE `registries`.`user_registry_id` = 14 LIMIT 1
```

Is my relationship not set up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My relationships were in fact incorrect.

```
class UserRegistry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :page
    has_one :registry
    attr_accessible :page_id, :registry_id, :url
end
```

The foreign key is in user registries, so instead of a has_one relationship, I needed belongs_to, like so.

```
class UserRegistry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :page
    belongs_to :registry
    attr_accessible :page_id, :registry_id, :url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think it has anything to do with relationship. Could you make sure that there is a column "user_registry_id" in the table "registries" and also in your case, I believe it is supposed to be set up as a foreign key.

Comment: There isn't a user_registry_id column, because there shouldn't be on the "many" side of the many to one relationship.  There are many user_registries for each registry*.

Comment: yeah, you're right. But I still cannot see anything wrong in your mapping. Probably you might want to consider a Join query, cuz in the WHERE clause of your query, you have a condition against column 'user_registry_id', which you confirm does not exist. By the way, I'm not really a Ruby dev, so hopefully a Ruby guru could give a simple clear answer :)